# What is the argument for continuity here

Tags: functional-analysis

Here is a paragraph in Murphy's book on operator theory:

[image]

[image]

I don't understand how continuity of $z \mapsto \tau_z$ follows from the continuity of $z \mapsto \tau_z(f)$. If $f \circ g$ is continuous and one of the two functions is continuous it does not follow that the other is, too. The map $z \mapsto \tau_z(f)$ is  a composition with the evaluation map $T_f: \tau \mapsto \tau(f)$. This map is continuous but even if the composition is shown to be continuous it does not imply that $z \mapsto \tau_z$ is continuous. Could anyone help me understand what is meant here?

Comment: I do not know these objects, but the topology on $\Omega(\ell^1(Z))$ might be defined exactly so that this holds. Topologies like that are often called weak topologies in Functional Analysis (more generally they are known as initial topologies with respect to a set of functions). So what is the topology here?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Yes, exactly, the topology on $\Omega$ is the weak $\ast$ topology hence the evaluation maps $\tau \mapsto \tau(f)$ are continuous. But my question is: why does it then follow that $z \mapsto \tau_z$ is continuous. In this notation $\Omega$ denotes the character space.

Comment: Note that in the map that is supposedly continuous the $\Omega$ is in the range not in the domain.

Comment: The weak-$*$-topology is not only *a* topology such that the evaluation maps are continuous (then you would be right), but *the smallest* such topology. Hence for a function to this space to be continuous is suffices that the compositions with all evaluation maps are continuous. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology for the general concept.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz I'm still not clear about this. If $X \to Y \to Z$ where $g:X \to Y$ and $Y$ has the weak star topology and $f \circ g$ is continuous for every $f$ an evaluation map how does it follow that $g$ is continuous?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Could one finish the argument like this? There are no open sets in the middle space $Y$ other than those that are in the inverse range of the evaluation maps.

Comment: Not exactly right, but preimages of open sets $\mathbb C$ under the evaluation maps form a sub-basis of the topology. Same idea.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Thank you, yes that's what I was trying to say.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz please compose this comments into the single answer

Comment: @Norbert, you are right, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this comes back to the topology that is used on $\Omega(\ell^1(\mathbb Z))$. The topology here is the weak-$*$-topology, which is the [initial topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology) with respect to the evaluation functions $T_f\colon\Omega(\ell^1(\mathbb Z))\to \mathbb C$, $T_f(\tau)=\tau(f)$. Now the property that characterises this topology is that indeed a function $h\colon X\to\Omega(\ell^1(\mathbb Z))$ is continuous if and only if all $T_f\!\circ\! h$ are continuous.